# How to use Camel Apache Timer Component

Tags: java, timer, apache-camel

So currently, the only thing that we can work out is to simply transfer one file to another folder.
Like so:

```
from("file://C:/Users/Me/Desktop/FolderA?noop=true")
    .to("file://C:/Users/Me/Desktop/FolderB");
```

However, when I try to add the complexity of the timer component, it just does not make sense to me. I keep getting "Cannot write null body to file" exception.

The code I try to write for the timer Component is like so:

```
from("timer://file://C:/Users/Me/Desktop/FolderA?period=30000")
    .to("file://C:/Users/Me/Desktop/FolderB");
```

Comment: http://camel.apache.org/file2.html has options for polling file. It polls folders.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried:

```
from("timer://file://C:/Users/Me/Desktop/FolderA?fixedRate=true&period=30s")
    .to("file://C:/Users/Me/Desktop/FolderB");
```

And instead of using "30000" you could use "30s" which is more friendly to read.

Check [this out](http://camel.apache.org/timer.html).

Answer (score 0):

Use timer with pollEnrich

```
from("timer://foo?period=30000")
   .pollEnrich("file://C:/Users/Me/Desktop/FolderA?noop=true")
   .to("file://C:/Users/Me/Desktop/FolderB");
```